# struts 2 many to one association example

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2, ognl

In jsp i am using ognl expression for list of department.and have two bean class student and department.Using Hibernate Many to one association.Student bean contains Department dept_id; field.

Student.class

```
public class Student {

    private int id;
    private String studentName;
    private Department dept_id;

    public Student() {}

    public Student(int id,String studentName,Department dept_id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.dept_id = dept_id;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public Department getDept_id() {
        return dept_id;
    }

    public void setDept_id(Department dept_id) {
        this.dept_id = dept_id;
    }
}
```

Department.class

```
public class Department {

    private int dept_id;
    private String deptName;

    public Department() {}

    public Department(int dept_id,String deptName) {
        this.dept_id = dept_id;
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }

    public int getDept_id() {
        return dept_id;
    }

    public void setDept_id(int dept_id) {
        this.dept_id = dept_id;
    }

    public String getDeptName() {
        return deptName;
    }

    public void setDeptName(String deptName) {
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
<s:form action="insertData">
<s:textfield name = "studentName" label = "Name"/>
<s:select  list="#{'1':'IT', '2':'COM', '3':'EC'}" name="dept_id" 
label="Select Department"/> 
<s:submit value = "Submit"/>
</s:form>
```

now while getting select tag value.it is in string and i have to store dept_id in object form because i am using foreign key in database.how to get object value in action class?

Comment: binding properties of the action to the form

Comment: Submit some id and fetch from db in action.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to be able to get a Map<String, Integer> where the String would be the Department name and the Integer is the department id? That way when you create/update/delete the Department table, your select will still have the right keys? If so, you need a service to fetch that data (function that gets what you need, you could just leave it as a List<Department>), then my personal preference would be to drop the s:select in favour of normal html but I would use an s:iterator over a list of <option> tags adding the appropriate value, I would find that pretty clear.

Comment: Actually the select tag is getting value in String and in bean class it is setting in object.so i used type converter and issue was solved.